# Does $(1093)^2|2^{1092}-1$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I have this problem:

Show that $(1093)^2|2^{1092}-1$.

By this | I mean divide. I would like to write here my progress but I have absolutely no clue how to do show that it divides. Any ideas? Thanks